# How do I set the command in the tasks.json file from "Command Palette"?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Example command:
`editor.action.goToDeclaration`

Like this:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "gotoD",
            "type": "vscode",
            "command": "editor.action.goToDeclaration"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to create your own shortcut to that command? Of course it already has one : F12 .  Otherwise, what are you trying to accomplish with a task?

Comment: goToDeclaration is for example.
I want use Status Bar Tasks - one click - do shell commands and after do Start Debug. I know "preLaunchTask" in launch.json, but use this in Task is better and more comfortable. It gives more freedom.
Even nevest status bar Button for Debugging is less comfortable.

Comment: Can you please post what you are trying to accomplish instead. Using tasks in this way seems misguided

Comment: One click - remove some temp files and run make file and run vscode-debugger. This button must be on statusbar(one click!).

Answer (score 0):

You can have commands in your tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "My Command",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [],
            "command": "${command:my-command}",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "never",
                "panel": "shared",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_settings-command-variables-and-input-variables